# wpf DelegateCommand and ValidationRules

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm

i have have the `TimePicker` and validation rules

```
<controls:TimePicker Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Culture="Ru-ru" Margin="5,5,5,2.5">
            <controls:TimePicker.SelectedTime>
                <Binding Path="EditTimeStart" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnValidationError="True" >
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                         ......
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </controls:TimePicker.SelectedTime>
        </controls:TimePicker>
```

and a button ("Save").

```
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}"/>
```

in my ViewModel

```
SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save, CanSave);
```

where `CanSave` method process another сonditions (conditions not intersect with ValidationRules)

QUESTION. Can i SaveButton enable binding to validationriles and `CanSave` method?

Comment: Validation in the UI is a bad idea for this particular reason. Better to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo, which shows errors in the UI and that you can query from your CanSave method.

Comment: Why is bad idea? Except i can not call CanSave method

Comment: It's a bad idea because you cannot access validation errors that are defined in the UI from within your view model.

Comment: Implementing validation logic in the views breaks the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @mm8 When I can use the ValidationRule to not break the MVVM pattern

Comment: For example when you want to customize the error message that shows up when the typed in value cannot be converted to the type of the source property as exlained in the blog post. Then you never get to the setter of the view model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you follow the MVVM pattern and bind to command properties of a view model, you should generally implement the validation logic in your view model class rather than using validation rules.

You do this by implementing either the `IDataErrorInfo` interface or the newer and more flexible `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface that was introduced in .NET Framework 4.5. Please refer to the following blog post for more information: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/.